# Clearing List and re-adding objects leads to same number of objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a `List` that stores all `child gameobjects`.

```
List<GameObject> goChildren = new List<GameObject>();
```

In the Start() function i have this:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    goChildren.Add(child.gameObject);
}
```

to add all children.

Then i have a "Hit()"-Method, which is called when the player hits one of the child-objects.

Then the child-object should get destroyed, the List should be cleared and all remaining objects should be added again.

This is how i try to handle this:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, actionRange))
{
    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
}

goChildren.Clear();
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    goChildren.Add(child.gameObject);
}
```

But then i have the same number of objects stored in my List goChildren than before.

I used `Debug.Log(goChildren.Count)` to display the number of children before the Hit()-Method and after it.

And both tell me that i have 566 Children in my List.

> What i thought that this code should do is:
>
> 1. Destroy one child
> 2. Clear the List
> 3. Add the remaining children to the List

Comment: Why not just remove one from the list instead of clearing it and adding remaining every time?

Comment: How can i get the correct one in the list? Something like going through all of them and check if hit.transform.gameObject == goChildren[i]? Wouldn't that be nearly the same thing then deleting and adding all again?

Comment: There is a [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) function that takes one item to remove from the list (has to be the exact same item).  There is also [`RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2) which takes a predicate.  You can also use Linq for this

Comment: `Destroy()` does not immediately destroy the object, it in fact, may still exist in memory and be referenced for up to a minute afterwards (when it gets garbage collected), although attempting to do anything with it will throw an `object had been destroyed, but a script is still trying to reference it` error. As such, it may still exist in the transform hierarchy, even if it isn't really there.

Comment: @Draco18s okay, didn't knew that. Is there a way to manually garbage collect?

Comment: Option A: HG Sandhagen's answer. Option B: compare with null before adding to the list (that said, what point does the list serve?) Option F: `DestroyImmediate()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, actionRange))
{
    goChildren.Remove(hit.transform.gameObject);
    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), the object destroy happens after the current update loop. So actually the object still exists (and the transform list item has reference to it) at the time, when you refill the list.
So the better solution is to remove the element reference from the list by

```
goChildren.Remove(***obj reference***)
```

or

```
goChildren.RemoveAt(***obj index***)
```

and then destroy the gameobject.
Furthermore, there is no point of removing and readding unmodified changes, it generates a lot of unnecessary array-modifications behind the scenes for no reason. (The Remove and RemoveAt functions also copy the shifted part after the deleted element, which can be a huge work, if the removed element is at the beginning of a big list.)

Note that adding huge amount of elements for a new list is extremely suboptimal, as the array behind the list is reallocated and copied over and over again.
The default capacity of a list is 4, and when the size exceeds it, it allocates a new array with size of 8, then copies the contents. The same happens with 16, 32, 64 and so on, so when you fill a List from 0 to 566 elements, then

1. allocates 4
2. allocates 8, copy
3. allocates 16, copy
4. 32, copy
5. 64, copy
6. 128, copy
7. 256, copy
8. 512, copy
9. 1024, copy

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef)

You can preallocate a List by

```
List<GameObject> goChildren = new List<GameObject>(capacity);
```

but this is just an initial performance gain, try to use

`HashSet<T>`

if the order of the elements is not important. All you need is a good Hash function, which can be achieved easily in most cases.

Comment: I learned a thing. I will start pre-allocating my lists from now on.